# Improve Performance when returning data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that produces 2,675 records in about 10 seconds in SQL Server Management Studio.

However, when I call it from my C# application, it takes 1:05 to fill the `DataTable`. Is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Here is how I am filling the `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string procName, params SqlParameter[] procParams)
{
    using (_conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = procName;

        if (procParams != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter p in procParams)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }

        _conn.Open();

        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        var table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);

        return table;
    }
}
```

It is specifically at this point:

```
var table = new DataTable();
da.Fill(table);
```

that almost all of the time is taken (almost 60 seconds).

I have worked with large data using this method before and haven't had this much of a delay.

Any suggestions or ideas?

**UPDATE:**

We also tried it with a `DataReader` like this:

```
var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
table.Load(dataReader);
dataReader.Close();
```

**UPDATE:**

Running the same sp for the same report in a desktop report viewer gets the results in under 12 seconds.  This is the same report run over the web and in the desktop.  Why is it so slow?

**Called SP:**

This is the SP run to get data for the report.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptCheckRegDetail]
@ldStartDt as char(10) = '',
@ldEndDt as char(10) = '',
@lcStartCkNo as char(10)= ' ',
@lcEndCkNo as char(10) =' ',
@lcUniqSupNo as char(10)=' ',
@lcBk_Uniq as char(10)= ' ',
@lnStatus as int=1

as
begin
  declare @ChkHd table  (ApChk_uniq char(10),Bank char(35),Bk_acct_no char(15),
      iCheckno char(10),Checkno char(10),CheckDate smalldatetime,
      SupName char(35),CheckAmt numeric(12,2),Status char(15), Detail char(6),
      CheckNote text,ReconcileStatus char(1),ReconciledDate smalldatetime)

  Insert into @ChkHd        
    exec [CheckRegView] @ldStartDt,@ldEndDt,@lcStartCkNo,@lcEndCkNo,@lcUniqSupNo,@lcBk_Uniq,@lnStatus                       

  SELECT c1.ApChk_uniq, c1.Bank, c1.Bk_acct_no, c1.iCheckno, c1.Checkno, 
    c1.CheckDate, c1.SupName,
    case when 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c1.apchk_uniq order by c1.checkno) = 1 
      then CheckAmt else cast(0.00 as numeric(12,2)) end as CheckAmt,
    c1.status,c1.checknote,Apchkdet.item_no, Apchkdet.ponum, Apchkdet.invno,
    Apchkdet.invdate, Apchkdet.due_date, Apchkdet.item_desc, Apchkdet.invamount, 
    Apchkdet.disc_tkn, Apchkdet.aprpay,Apchkdet.apchk_uniq, Apchkdet.itemnote, 
    MICSSYS.LIC_NAME
      FROM      @ChkHd as C1 
        inner join apchkdet on apchkdet.APCHK_UNIQ = c1.ApChk_uniq
        cross join micssys
      ORDER BY  Checkno,Apchkdet.item_no
end
```

Comment: Can you return a `SqlDataReader` instead? They're forward-only and take up a lot less resources. They'll be much quicker too. What are you doing with the `DataTable`?

Comment: I am returning the DataTable and using it in a report.  I don't think I can stream the rows to the report.

Comment: You could try to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` just to measure how long it takes to execute the call from C# without filling any data table to get a better comparison value.

Comment: How large are the individual rows?  Also, please post the code for the stored procedure.

Comment: The sp completes in about 10 seconds in SSMS and returns 2612 rows on this particular db.  While it isn't nearly instantaneous, that isn't the bulk of the time required to populate the table.

Comment: Show you sp please (you could just be suffering from some parameter sniffing).

Comment: Don't use a table. When someone suggested using a datareader they meant directly. Not using a DataTable to load a reader.

Comment: @uriDium How do I send the data to the Crystal Report other than via a `DataTable`?

Comment: @Serge If the sp runs in about 10 seconds (worst case) how would that account for 60+ seconds when run through my C# code?

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlDataAdapter` is inherently slow when it creates a `DataTable`. Because the query executes relatively quickly in SSMS it'll probably be the population of the `DataTable` that is the main issue.

If all you're doing is reading the data and listing it out somewhere else it would be more efficient to create a list of `Dictionary<string, object>` using a `SqlDataReader`.

Your method could be replaced by something like this:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDataTable(string procName, params SqlParameter[] procParams)
{
    using (_conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = procName;

            if (procParams != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter p in procParams)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
            }

            _conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                       string fieldName = reader.GetName(i);
                       row.Add(fieldName, reader[fieldName]);
                    }

                    result.Add(row);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should nearly work! :)

You can then loop through the rows like this:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> field in result)
    {
        string fieldName = field.Key;
        string fieldValue = field.Value.ToString(); // Cast to correct type here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have have a `DataTable` for the report.  While streaming it to a `Dictionary`, then converting to a `DataTable` really be faster than just going to a `DataTable` directly?

Comment: Oh, no, that won't be faster :) Thought you were just rendering the results in the report directly. Can you change the report implementation to use the solution above?

Comment: We are using Crystal Reports for VS2010.  I am not aware of a way to use a Dictionary as the datasource, so I don't think so.

Comment: We tried using a DataReader instead of DataAdapter, at it still took over a minute to simply fill a DataTable. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you append an update to your question with the new code you're using to retrieve the data?

Comment: It's the population of the data structure triggered by `table.Load(dataReader);` that takes the time. If you can't pass anything else to the report that's quicker to populate you'll need to either split the report up into smaller result sets, use a custom report generation utility that you'd need to make yourself, or just wait :)

Comment: I can't believe that Crystal Reports loads the data faster and better (10 seconds total) on the desktop than C# is able to load the same data from the same db into a DataTable (60+ seconds just for the DataTable).  How disappointing for C#.

Comment: Actually it's unfortunate that the Crystal Reports API will only accept a `DataTable` as input. It's definitely not the most efficient construct. Would be better if they could use an `IDataReader` or something instead. I wonder if there is a newer version that accepts a different type?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what I found.  The SQLDataAdapter apparently has a problem with the SmallDateTime variable.  Cast the SmallDateTime as a normal DateTime and it should speed up the DataReader.

So, cast the smalldatetime sql as follows:

```
Cast(@smalldatetimevar as datetime) smalldatetimevar
```

When I did this in my project, the table.Load(dataReader) command went from timing out to returning the resultset immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it is the application or the SQL Server that is slow use [SQL Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181091.aspx)  an trace the executed query.